# さま after a verb

Tags: meaning, dictionary

I found in different occasions `さま` after a verb, but I'm not sure about its meaning.  For example, in [大辞林's definition for 半ば](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%8D%8A%E3%81%B0):

> ある状態に半分ほどなっているさま
>
> （「…てはじめて」の形で）さまざまな経過を経てようやくその状態になるさま

I noticed both times it's a `なるさま` form, so I'm not sure if it's a fixed form, but I can't find it on Weblio, so maybe not.

Maybe it's meaning 3 [on Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%95%E3%81%BE) (state; situation; appearance), but if that's the case I don't really undestand what does it mean in those sentences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

さま (様) just means "state" or "appearance", the same as 状態 or 様子.

See the first definition in [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%A7%98_%28%E3%81%95%E3%81%BE%29/):

> さま【様／▽方】 の解説
>   ［名］
>   １ 物事や人のありさま。ようす。状態。「雲のたなびく―が美しい」「物慣れた―に振る舞う」

It's used heavily in dictionaries in this way, and also in formal texts/presentations, but you're not likely to encounter it in everyday life outside of those situations.

As to how to interpret it, borrowing your examples we have:

> ある状態に半分ほどなっているさま → The state of having become roughly halfway a certain way

and

> さまざまな経過を経てようやくその状態になるさま → The state of finally becoming a certain way after having gone through various things

and for an example without なる (from the definition of 断然):

> 程度が他から非常にかけ離れているさま → The state of the extent/degree of something being far removed from others.